# Different directories for seed data using sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I would like to have different seed data between development and production. How can I specify this in the configuration? I'm aware that in the `.sequelizerc` I can load a dynamic configuration file and specify a `seeders-path`

```
// .sequelizerc
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  "config": path.resolve('./app/config', 'config.json'),
   "models-path": path.resolve('./app/models'),
   "migrations-path": path.resolve('./app/migrations')
   "seeders-path": path.resolve('./app/seeders')
}
```

And the config

```
// ./app/config/config.json
{
  "development": {
     // environment specific configuration
     ...
```

Is it possible to choose the `seeders-path` within the dynamic configuration? Or shall I make some logic like

```
"seeders-path": process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'? 
  "seeders/development" :
  "seeders/production"
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use npm scripts something like this:

```
// package.json
"scripts": { 
    "sequelize:prod": "sequelize $* --seeders-path seeders/production", 
    "sequelize:dev": "sequelize $* --seeders-path seeders/development",
}
```

Or you can pass config directly like this:

```
// package.json
"scripts": {
    "sequelize:dev": "sequelize $* --config some/path/dev.js"
    "sequelize:prod": "sequelize $* --config some/path/prod.js"
}
```

Lists of options that u can pass to sequelize:

1. **--env** *string* The environment to run the command in
2. **--config** *string* The path to the config file
3. **--options-path** *string* The path to a JSON file with additional options
4. **--migrations-pat** *string* The path to the migrations folder
5. **--seeders-path** *string* The path to the seeders folder
6. **--models-path** *string* The path to the models folder
7. **--url** *string* The database connection string to use. Alternative to using --config files
8. **--debug** *bolean* When available show various debug information bolean

In sequelize-cli sources have this code [link](https://github.com/sequelize/cli/blob/5633648ecb6d81b3fdeafadd5ee1c9e6fb350dd5/src/core/yargs.js#L5):

```
function loadRCFile(optionsPath) {


const rcFile = optionsPath || path.resolve(process.cwd(), '.sequelizerc');
  const rcFileResolved = path.resolve(rcFile);
  return fs.existsSync(rcFileResolved)
    ? JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(require(rcFileResolved)))
    : {};
}

const args = yargs
  .config(loadRCFile(yargs.argv.optionsPath));
```

So you can load different files like ".sequelizerc":

```
// package.json
"scripts": {
    "sequelize:dev": "sequelize $* --options-path some/path/dev.js"
    "sequelize:prod": "sequelize $* --options-path some/path/prod.js"
}

// some/path/dev.js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
   "config": path.resolve('./app/config', 'config.json'),
   "models-path": path.resolve('./app/models'),
   "migrations-path": path.resolve('./app/migrations')
   // here your development path to seeders
   "seeders-path": path.resolve('./app/seeders/development')
}

// some/path/prod.js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
   "config": path.resolve('./app/config', 'config.json'),
   "models-path": path.resolve('./app/models'),
   "migrations-path": path.resolve('./app/migrations')
   // here your development path to seeders
   "seeders-path": path.resolve('./app/seeders/production')
}
```

But u can create seeders for different ENV in one seeder directory.

Lets say, we have .sequelizerc

```
// .sequelizerc
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
   "config": path.resolve('./app/config', 'config.json'),
   "models-path": path.resolve('./app/models'),
   "migrations-path": path.resolve('./app/migrations')
   "seeders-path": path.resolve('./app/seeders')
}
```

Create seeders:

```
sequelize seed:generate --name create_users-dev.js
sequelize seed:generate --name create_users-prod.js
sequelize seed:generate --name create_users-whatever.js
```

And we run only dev seeders:

```
sequelize db:seed --seed `basename $(ls app/seeders/*-dev.js)`
```

or prod seeders:

```
sequelize db:seed --seed `basename $(ls app/seeders/*-prod.js)`
```

or just users dev seeders

```
sequelize db:seed --seed `basename $(ls app/seeders/*users-dev.js)`
```

You can choose what seeder u want to run.

Format:

```
sequelize db:seed --seed <array>
sequelize db:seed --seed file1 file2 fileN
```

Comment: Could you explain the area where you say "In sources have this code:"?  Where is this code located in a typical Node app?

Comment: @G.Deward I mean sequelize-cli sources [see here](https://github.com/sequelize/cli/blob/5633648ecb6d81b3fdeafadd5ee1c9e6fb350dd5/src/core/yargs.js#L5)

Comment: I came here for the trick about selectively running additional seeders in a development environment, without having to specify an entirely different seeder path. I did not want to have duplicate copies (or symlinks) for every production seeder, and I did not want to have to specify every single seeder file at the prompt.

Answer (score 3):

Here i used the below command to execute the specific file in the seeders folder of Sequelize.

Command:-
**sequelize db:seed --seed [seed file name]**

like:-

Example:-
**sequelize db:seed --seed 20181204125705-executiveholds**

Comment: I don't why Sequelize doesn't add this into its docs. Thanks man.