# Sequelize CLI: How do I keep test data seeders from running in production?

Tags: sequelize.js

Right now, I want to establish a subset of seeders to be applied only to testing environments.

[image]

For example, in this screenshot I want the seeder directly under 'seeders' to be applied to all environments but for the seeder under 'test' to only be applied to my local machine's database.

Is there a way in Sequelize to establish different namespaces for migrations and seeders?

I want to be able to run a command something like this:

```
npx sequelize-cli db:seed --subset test
```

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46396175/different-directories-for-seed-data-using-sequelize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sequelize won't be environment-aware.  You could either build logic *inside* the seeder to detect the environment and run things differently (bad idea), or you can set up separate folders for prod vs test environments.  I would STRONGLY recommend that test environments run ALL the prod seeders, but not vice-versa.  You want to have well-tested prod seeders when you get to production.  In fact, I would suggest that "stage" mirror what happens in production, so that local/dev(feature) runs the extra test seeders, but stage and prod run only production seeders.

See also this answer for some specific ideas: [Different directories for seed data using sequelize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46396175/different-directories-for-seed-data-using-sequelize)